Troubleshooting '400 Bad Request' Error in Mailchimp addStoreProduct API Call
   public function test(){  
      
  require_once '.././././vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    $client = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();
    $client->setConfig([
        'apiKey' => env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'),
        'server' => env('MAILCHIMP_SERVER')
    ]);
    $store_id = env('MAILCHIMP_STORE_ID');
    print_r($store_id);
    $products = Product::with('translations')->get();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_id = $product->id;
        print_r($store_id); 
        $response = $client->ecommerce->getProductVariants($store_id, $product_id);
        print_r($response);  :

    } 
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {

           dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}

}
        Products table: Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('ean')->nullable();
        $table->string('sku')->nullable();
        $table->integer('brand_id')->nullable();
        $table->double('stock')->nullable();
        $table->double('stock_multiply')->default(1);
        $table->string('wp_availability')->nullable();
        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('edited_by')->nullable();
        $table->integer('wp_id')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
        $table->boolean('manage_stock')->default(0);
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

};
ProductTranslations table(en,hu,ro)
      Schema::create('product_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('locale')->index();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->text('short_description')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->text('specifications')->nullable();
        $table->text('sizing_guide')->nullable();
        $table->text('questions_and_answers')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();

        $table->unique(['product_id', 'locale'], 'product_id_locale');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

NewsletterController:
    public function test()
    {
  require_once '.././././vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();
$client->setConfig([
    'apiKey' => env('MAILCHIMP_APIKEY'),
    'server' => env('MAILCHIMP_SERVER')
]);
$store_id = env('MAILCHIMP_STORE_ID');

try {
    $products = Product::with('translations')->get();
    foreach ($products as $product) {

            $response = $client->ecommerce->addStoreProduct($store_id, [
                "id" => $product->id,
                "title" => $product->title,
                "handle" => $product->slug,
                "description" => $product->description,
                "variants" => [
                    [
                        "id" => $product->id,
                        "title" => $product->title,
                        "price" => $product->price,
                        "inventory_quantity" => $product->stock,
                        "description" => $product->description,
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
            print_r($response);
        }

} catch (\MailchimpMarketing\ApiException $e) {
    echo "Error: Failed to add product.\n";
    echo "Status: " . $e->getCode() . "\n";
    echo "Detail: " . json_encode($e->getResponseBody(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "\n";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: An unexpected error occurred.\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

I can write out all the data for the product in the foreach, but I can't add it to the store, but it's empty. I  can acces the getAllStoreProducts function, getProductVariants everything is working...
I have no idea and this is my first time using mailchimp. print_r(store_id) = example_storeexample_store,so its ok. And the getProductVariants its ok their 96 product works well, but there is no problem with that either

According to https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/ecommerce-products/add-product/, the parameters title and variants are also required for the add product endpoint, but you appear to be supplying only store ID and product ID?

products table : ean,sku,brand_id,stock,,wp_availability,price,user_id,edited_by,wp_id,status,manage_stock and product_translations table : product_id,locale(en,hu),title,short_description,specifications  $table->unique(['product_id', 'locale'], 'product_id_locale');
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

And I tried like this:  $products = Product::with('translations')->get();
foreach ($products as $product) {$response = $client->ecommerce->addStoreProduct($store_id, [
"id" =>$product->id,
"title" => $product->translations->first()->title,
"variants" => [
[
"id" => $product->id,
"title" => $product->translations->first()->title,
"price" => $product->price,
]
],
]);
print_r($response); but still the same error

That's hard to read in comments, can you please edit your question and add the new code there, properly formatted.

and my image url is in another table

Your question originally contained "detail":"The r (truncated...) as part of the API response / exception message. See to it that you get the full API response, untruncated - there's likely to be more information about what exactly it didn't like in there.

"{"type":"https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/","title":"Resource Not Found","status":404,"detail":"The requested resource could not be found.","instance":"ee573d61-fbd7-f3a0-c112-fe4921d78ab4"}"
this is the detail

According to their docs, "Resource Not Found: The requested resource could not be found. Either no object exists with the ID provided in the path, or the path is incorrect." Have you verified the $store_id you are passing? That's the only thing that actually goes into the path for this request (/ecommerce/stores/{store_id}/products), so I'm guessing either that value is not correct, or it might be one you don't have access to with the given credentials.

stdClass Object ( [store_id] => example_store [product_id] => 1 [variants] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1-v1 [title] => Miere  g [url] => [sku] => [price] => 22 [inventory_quantity] => 19 [image_url] => [backorders] => [visibility] => [created_at] => 2024-07-10T08:56:30+00:00 [updated_at] => 2024-07-10T08:56:30+00:00
